# Is there any way to use constant (EnumType Ordinal) value in @Query annotation in JPA repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Enum,

```
public enum CountEnum {
   ONE,
   TWO
}
```

Entity class,

```
@Entity
public class Test {
...
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CountEnum countEnum;
...
}
```

I want to query all the `Test` rows having countEnum  `'ONE'`. But as here `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` is ordinal, I have to put int value of `'ONE'` in `@Query` instead of String.

My Repository Interface,

```
public interface ResourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, String> {
    @Query(" select test from Test test where test.countEnum = " + CountEnum.ONE.ordinal())
    List<Test> find();
}
```

But it throws an error saying  `Attribute value must be constant`. So how do I will query all those rows using ordinal value of enum as I don't want to put hardcoded constant values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think you have to use the ordinal value when writing JPQL?

The JPA Specification says:

> ### 4.6.1 Literals
>
> [...]
>   Enum literals support the use of Java enum literal syntax. The fully qualified enum class name must be specified.

I therefore would expect something like the following to work:

```
public interface ResourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, String> {
    @Query(" select test from Test test where test.countEnum = com.somepackage.with.sub.pakcages.CountEnum.ONE")
    List<Test> find();
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me, although it seems totally valid and was my initial way to try it. Getting `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'com.example.Class.Enum'`. Maybe caused by the inner enum?

Answer (score 1):

Use conventional methods like:

```
public interface ResourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, String> {

    List<Test> findByCountEnum(CountEnum ce);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the query as a String constant:

```
private static final String QUERY_FIND = " select test from Test test where test.countEnum = " + CountEnum.ONE.ordinal();
```

Then use the constant in the annotation:

```
public interface ResourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, String> {
    @Query(QUERY_FIND)
    List<Test> find();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign constant values to enum:

```
public enum CountEnum {
    ONE(Constants.ONE_VALUE), TWO(Constants.TWO_VALUE);

    CountEnum(int countEnum) {
    }

    public static class Constants  {
        public static final int ONE_VALUE = 0;
        public static final int TWO_VALUE = 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can use enum in `@Query`annotation:

```
public interface ResourceRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, String> {
    @Query(" select test from Test test where test.countEnum = " + CountEnum.Constants.ONE_VALUE)
    List<Test> find();
}
```